# (SwiftUI, MacOS 11.0) How to detect focus in SecureTextFeild?

Tags: macos, swiftui, textfield

I'm using SwiftUI to develop a new macOS application and can't figure out how to detect focus in SecureTextFeild. I want to change the color of the border when I type or exceed a certain number of characters.(not 12.0 Beta...) TextFeild work well, but SecureTextFeild don't know what to do it. Here is my code

```
                HStack {
                    Image(idFocus ? "person_blue" : "person_grey")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 14, height: 14)
                        .padding(.leading, 15)
                    TextField("id".localString(language), text: $id, onEditingChanged: {(changed) in
                        idFocus = true
                    }) {
                        if id.isEmpty{ idFocus = false }
                    }
                    .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                    .onTapGesture {
                        idFocus = true
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 241, height: 42)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(idFocus ? Color.mainColor() : Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                
                HStack {
                    Image(pwFocus ? "lock_blue" : "lock_grey")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 14, height: 14)
                        .padding(.leading, 15)
                    SecureField("password".localString(language), text: $password)
                        .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                        
                    
                }
                .padding(.top, 6)
                .frame(width: 241, height: 42)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(pwFocus ? Color.mainColor() : Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
```

And NSTextField extension code

```
extension NSTextField {
open override var focusRingType: NSFocusRingType {
    get {.none}
    set {}
}
```

}

Can I know the code that can be SecureTextField like TextField?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this:
(note that onFocus will be deprecated in macos12)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var idFocus = false
    @State var pwFocus = false
    
    @State var password = ""
    @State var id = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Image(idFocus ? "person_blue" : "person_grey")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 14, height: 14)
                    .padding(.leading, 15)
                TextField("id", text: $id, onEditingChanged: {(changed) in
                    idFocus = true
                }) {
                    if id.isEmpty{ idFocus = false}
                }
                .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                .onTapGesture {
                    idFocus = true
                }
                .onFocus{ val in     // <---
                    idFocus = val
                    pwFocus = !val
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 241, height: 42)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(idFocus ? Color.red : Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
            
            HStack {
                Image(pwFocus ? "lock_blue" : "lock_grey")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 14, height: 14)
                    .padding(.leading, 15)
                SecureField("password", text: $password)
                    .onFocus{ val in    // <---
                        pwFocus = val
                        idFocus = !val
                    }
                    .border(pwFocus ? Color.red : Color.gray) // <---
                    .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
            }
            .padding(.top, 6)
            .frame(width: 241, height: 42)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(pwFocus ? Color.red : Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
            
        }.frame(width: 444, height: 444)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the minimum OS version is 11.0, so this doesn't work. Do you know how to use .focusable or focusedValue?